# Using SeedSequence to convert any random seed into a good seed

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random, random-seed

In NumPy 1.17, the `random` module was given an overhaul. Among the new additions were [`SeedSequence`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/generated/numpy.random.SeedSequence.html#numpy.random.SeedSequence). In the section about [parallel random number generation in the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/parallel.html), `SeedSequence` is said to

> ensure that low-quality seeds are turned into high quality initial states

which supposedly mean that one can safely use a seed of e.g. `1`, as long as this is processed through a `SeedSequence` prior to seeding the PRNG. However, the rest of the documentation page goes on to describe how `SeedSequence` can turn one seed into several, independent PRNGs. What if we only want one PRNG, but want to be able to safely make use of small/bad seeds?

I have written the below test code, which uses the Mersenne twister `MT19937` to draw normal distributed random numbers. The basic seeding (without using `SeedSequence`) is `MT19937(seed)`, corresponding to `f()` below. I also try `MT19937(SeedSequence(seed))`, corresponding to `g()`, though this results in exactly the same stream. Lastly, I try using the `spawn`/`spawn_key` functionality of `SeedSequence`, which does alter the stream (corresponding to `h()` and `i()`, which produce identical streams).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f():
    return np.random.Generator(np.random.MT19937(seed))
def g():
    return np.random.Generator(np.random.MT19937(np.random.SeedSequence(seed)))
def h():
    return np.random.Generator(np.random.MT19937(np.random.SeedSequence(seed).spawn(1)[0]))
def i():
    return np.random.Generator(np.random.MT19937(np.random.SeedSequence(seed, spawn_key=(0,))))

seed = 42  # low seed, contains many 0s in binary representation
n = 100
for func, ls in zip([f, g, h, i], ['-', '--', '-', '--']):
    generator = func()
    plt.plot([generator.normal(0, 1) for _ in range(n)], ls)
plt.show()
```

##### Question

Are `h()` and `i()` really superior to `f()` an `g()`? If so, why is it necessary to invoke the spawn (parallel) functionality, just to convert a (possibly bad) seed into a good seed? To me these seem like they ought to be disjoint features.

Comment: "Are h() and i() really superior to f() an g()?" - no. Why did you think they might be? It seems like you've got some misunderstanding here that "no" wouldn't be enough to clarify.

Comment: Say I later run my program with `seed = 43` (rather than `42`). I want the two executions to have completely independent random streams. This is supposedly not the case for `f()` and `g()`, at least.

Comment: "This is supposedly not the case for f() and g(), at least." - why do you think that?

Comment: From the linked docs: "The Mersenne Twister algorithm suffers if there are too many 0s. Similarly, two adjacent 32-bit integer seeds (i.e. 12345 and 12346) would produce very similar streams."

Comment: ...wait. Are you assuming that the identical output from the `f` and `g` generators means `SeedSequence` didn't do anything? `np.random.MT19937(seed)` *already* uses a SeedSequence.

Comment: It does? This is not clear to me from the docs.

Comment: You're reading the documentation about parallel seed management techniques, not the documentation about `np.random.MT19937`. It's going to talk about parallel seed management techniques, not about how `np.random.MT19937` handles the seed argument.

Comment: If you look at the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/mt19937.html) for `np.random.MT19937`, you'll find the following: "If an int or array_like[ints] is passed, then it will be passed to SeedSequence to derive the initial BitGenerator state."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason nothing changed when you used an explicit `SeedSequence` is that the new randomness APIs already pass seeds through `SeedSequence` by default. It's not a sign that something went wrong, or that you need to explicitly call `spawn`. Calling `spawn` doesn't produce better output; it just produces different output.